# What size resistor to light 3.3V LEDs from a 3.3V circuit?

Tags: led, resistors

I have some blue LEDs that are listed at having a Vf of 3.3V @ 20mA.  If I want to drive them from a 3.3V source,  do I need a dropper resistor?  Methinks I do, but R = (3.3 - 3.3) / 0.02 = 0 Ohms!

I know that LEDs can be finicky about how they're driven, so is there a rule of thumb? (There's no data sheet as they're unbranded.)

Comment: No datasheet; No sale!  =-D

Comment: Boost the voltage and then use a resistor? LED Driver? You don't specify efficiency and cost requirement, so I guess that's fine. I think this type of question is somewhat funny puzzling.

Comment: What purpose do you want to drive these LEDs? To illuminate the entire room, or something else? And what kind is your "a 3.3V circuit"? A GPIO of a MCU, or a 5-mOhm MOSFET?

Comment: @Ale..chenski The duplicate wasn't recognised when I wrote the question. Thanks.